# CakePhp3.3 Error: Class 'CakeHaml\View\CakeHamlView' not found

Tags: cakephp

Pardon me as this is my first questions.
I tried to install a plugin for haml in cakephp 3 manually, and found this [k-motoyan/cake-haml](https://www.versioneye.com/php/k-motoyan:cake-haml/dev-master)

I can't install it using composer because I use cakephp 3.3.*

> k-motoyan/cake-haml dev-master requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.*-dev ->
>   no matching package found.

So, I tried to install it manually, downloading the zip and put it in [app]/plugins/kmotoyan/cakephp

I follow the readme setup

> ### Setup
>
> Add plugin load line to `config/bootstrap.php` file:
>
> `diff
>   + Plugin::load('CakeHaml', ['bootstrap' => true]);`
>
> Set the default ViewClass on the `src/Controller/AppController.php`
>   file:
>
> ```diff   class AppController extends Controller {
>
> - public $viewClass = 'CakeHaml\View\CakeHamlView'; ```
>
> You can use haml on all your view files with `.haml` extension.

and put this code below in my config/bootstrap.php

```
Plugin::load('kmotoyan/CakeHaml', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

and this code below in my src/Controller/AppController.php

```
public $viewClass = 'CakeHaml\\View\\CakeHamlView';
```

when I load the server, i get this error

> Error: Class 'CakeHaml\View\CakeHamlView' not found  File
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\qolega\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\ViewBuilder.php
>   Line: 363

when I see line 363 there's this line
`return new $className($request, $response, $events, $data);`

what should I do?

Comment: You trying to load form vendor/kmotoyan folder. Hint: use composer and save your time.

Comment: @salines I have been told you it requires cakephp3.0.* while I am using cakephp3.3.*

Comment: Fork it and change the version in the composer.json and use your fork or override the version via Composer. You'll find plenty of information on how to do that in the Composer documentation or on Google.

Comment: And/or create an issue / submit a patch to fix the problem in the package.